# Assembly language : How to Find square of a number in 1 address machine

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to calculate an expression : F = (A + B)^2 * C - A , on a 1 instruction machine.
I have wrote this code :

```
       LOAD A            
       ADD B
       ????????? MUL ????
       MUL C
       SUB A
       STORE F
```

But i don't know how to calculate the square of a+b. I know that i can calculate a+b 2 times and make a MUL , but is there a better way , for example to multiply accumulator with itself ???
Thank you !

Comment: "*I know that i can calculate a+b 2 times and make a MUL ...*" — ok, show us that.

Comment: @eric LOAD A   ADD B   STORE TEMP   LOAD TEMP   MUL TEMP   MUL C  SUB  A  STORE F

Comment: @alex Isn't that exactly what I already wrote in my answer? Possibly **not** needing the `LOAD TEMP`. Technically you did not calculate A+B a second time! `LOAD A` `ADD B` `STORE F` `LOAD A` `ADD B` `MUL F`

Comment: @alex, so that looks good and only computes A+B once.  As already stated in answer, you might be able to remove the `LOAD TEMP` since that value is probably already in the accumulator, having just computed & stored it.

Comment: You'd have to look to your instruction set to see if you can use the accumulator as an operand for `MUL`.  Some accumulator architectures (e.g. HP/1000-21MX) will let you use memory location 0 to actually indicate the accumulator, but that is not universal across all accumulator machines.  Otherwise, there'd have to be separate `MUL` that takes an alternate operand — and while this can be done there's little reason for the hardware to include such a specific operation when the store/mul from memory sequence works.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that i can calculate a+b 2 times and make a MUL , but is there a better way

Without any documentation about this architecture, here's an alternative:

```
   LOAD A            
   ADD B
   STORE F
   LOAD F   maybe not needed, could still be in accumulator
   MUL F
   MUL C
   SUB A
   STORE F
```

For "better", you'll need to share what's in the instruction set!

Comment: Ok , but about not needing the LOAD F line , is sure that when store the value of accumulator , he keeps the current value or is reset to empy value ?